# Running JerseyTest with PowerMock Exception for LoggingFeature.Verbosity

Tags: jersey-2.0, powermock, jersey-test-framework

### EDIT 1

pom.xml

```
<!-- Test Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you remove the `@PowerMockRunner` and `@PrepareForTest` attributes, then the test will run without an exception.

ConfigurationResourceTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ConfigurationResource.class })
public class ConfigurationResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ConfigurationResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        InputStream propertiesStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(propertiesStream);

        Configuration configuration = mock(Configuration.class);
        when(configuration.getProperties()).thenReturn(properties);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(Configuration.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(configuration);

        ConfigurationResource resource = new ConfigurationResource();

        final String config = resource.getConfiguration(null);

        assertEquals("{}", config);
    }

}
```

### ORIGINAL POST

When trying to use `@PowerMockRunner` and `@PrepareForTest` with JerseyTest and exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest. Reason: cannot find org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature$Verbosity

    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:145)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature$Verbosity
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:215)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:418)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:212)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1431)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:74)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature$Verbosity
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.toCtClass(Descriptor.java:592)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.getParameterTypes(Descriptor.java:439)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:188)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE] with listed dependencies

Comment: @peeskillet - made an edit.  is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Only problem I ran into was wit the Jersey 1.x dependency. You need to remove that.